# net logo patches patch-at error message

Tags: netlogo

I would like to ask about the current error message:

> You can't use patch-at in an observer context, because patch=at is
>   turtle/patch/only

```
globals [payoffs]

patches-own [payments]

to setup
  clear-all
  ; green: cooperate  red: defect
   ask patches [
    set pcolor green
    set payments [ ] 
   ]

ask patch-at 1 -1 [set pcolor red]

; cooperate 0  defect 1
set payoffs [[3 0] [4 1]]

   reset-ticks
   end

to go
  tick
  ask patches [
    play
  ]
  ask patches [
    update
  ]
end
```

Comment: Check the NetLogo Dictionary entry: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at  
The patch-at command reports a patch in a certain direction and distance from the *caller*. The caller in your case is the observer, but patch-at is only allowed to called by patches or turtles. If you just want the patch 1 -1 to turn red you just have to write: `ask patch 1 -1 [set pcolor red]`

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Model start running